# How do I extend PyGobject class when needing to instantiate with alternative signature?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm working with the Gtk.TextView in a project and I need to change how I'm instantiating the object so that I can include a custom TextBuffer in the TextView.

Currently my relevent code is:

```
# Relevant code only
class EditBox(Gtk.TextView):

    __gsignals__ = {
        # some signals
    }

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

This class instantiates and works perfectly thus far. The changes I'd like to make have me needing to use the `new_with_buffer` signature as documented [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/TextView.html#Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer). Simply passing in a buffer to the super statement does not solve the problem, and instantiating/calling a super.add_with_buffer() causes errors as well.

I need to be able to extend my EditBox in such a way that I can instantiate it using the `new_with_buffer` method in the parent, or be able to super in such a way that it instantiates correctly the way it is. I do not need to be able to instantiate without the buffer after this change is made.

I can instantiate the TextView itself using the `new_with_new` method, and pass it in a buffer, but I can't seem to figure out how to extend the TextView class in such a way that I can pass a buffer into my own extended class and have it passed on to the parent.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `kwargs` to the superclass constructor and giving a `buffer` property as a parameter to the constructor does the same as using `new_with_buffer`. `new_with_buffer` likely only exists as a convenience function for C programmers.

With the PyGObject-based bindings, [you can pass properties](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/properties.html) to the constructor with which they will be initialized.

```py
class EditBox(Gtk.TextView):
    …
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # do extra stuff

my_edit_box = EditBox(buffer=my_shared_buffer)
```